# What ex­act­ly is “lev­el shift” in trans­la­tion the­o­ry by Cat­ford?

Tags: grammar, translation

> Catford (1978) divides the shift in translation into two major types, level/rank shift and category shift. Level/rank shift refers to a source language item at one linguistic level that has a target language translation equivalent at a different level. In other words, it is simply a shift from grammar to lexis.

I don’t quite un­der­stand what the word ‘lev­el’ in *lev­el shift* refers to.
Lev­el of what?

The on­ly ex­am­ples I have found so far use present con­ti­nous or per­fect
con­struc­tions, such has *have been*, *to be + ‑ing*, &c.

But are there oth­er class­es of ex­am­ples of lev­el shift to be had?

For ex­am­ple,

- French: Elle est intelligente
- English: She's intelligent

in french, the adjective *intelligent* has *-e* in the end of it because its gender, but in english there's no system like that.
So does that count as lev­el shift?

Al­so in this ex­am­ple:

- French: les fleurs
- English: flow­er

The re­sult­ing trans­la­tion used sin­gu­lar not plu­ral like the source 
lan­guage did. Should this al­so to be con­sid­ered a lev­el shift?

also, for anyone who understand this in Bahasa Indonesia, i have another example.

French: Ils sont devenus trop grands

Indonesian: Mereka jadi kebesaran

the adjective "grand" has "-s" in the end because it follows the subject but there's no such thing as that in Indonesian. does it also considered as a level shift?

Comment: Citations? Quotes from Catford? Definitions? Where did the question come from?

Comment: @jlawler added it, is like that enough?

Comment: I think what Catford is talking about is a shift where meaning that originally was carried by grammar is carried by words in the translation, or vice versa. For example, some third person subjunctive constructions in French can be translated by the words *Let them ...*. For example, *qu'ils mangent de la brioche,* would be translated by *let them eat cake.* So what carries the meaning changes from grammar to lexis.

Comment: Another example of level shift would be superlatives. *The biggest house* in English becomes *la plus grande maison* in French. So you've translated the grammatical suffix *-est* into the word *plus.*

Comment: I'm curious: what circumstances were you thinking of where the natural translation of *les fleurs* would be *flower*? I'd guess that at least nine times out of ten, *flowers* or *the flowers* would be the right translation.

Comment: My actual problem was between French and Indonesian languange but i guess people wouldn't understand if I use Indonesian language, so I made the same problem but with English and not Indonesian. I know that the right translation would be _flowers_ but in this particular case that i encounter, the translation is just _flower_

Comment: If the Indonesian was something like *many flower*, it would be a level shift. But going from *jardin de fleurs* in French to *flower garden* in English isn't. You can't just switch languages like that in examples and get sensible answers.

Comment: it's not _many flower_ in Indonesian. it really is _flower_. It's a fault in translation and that's what I have to explain in my case. It's not 100% the same I know, if i use English as an example. But at least it really helps me a lot to understant it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, level refers, if I am understanding correctly, to the syntactic category. A same seme depending on language can be encoded by either a grammatical morpheme or a lexical morpheme. For example between French and English:

Je suis "en train d'" écrire

I am writ "ing"

The progressive seme is encoded differently in these two languages. In French, an adverbial phrase is used (so belonging to the lexical category) whereas in English, a verbal inflectional morpheme is used (so belonging to the grammatical category). Then, there is a syntactic category shift in the way where this aspect is encoded.

Comment: How about the suffixes like gender?  Like the suffix "-e" in my example above, do u think it's also a level shift?

Comment: It is not the case, because in English and partially in French, gender and number are not encoded on adjectives. In French, "e" is just a orthographic convention. Gender is mainly borne by personal pronouns.